# postgreSQL syntax error at or near "INSERT"

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my code:

```
SET SEARCH_PATH TO work

/* Task 1 */

INSERT INTO Category (CategoryID, Name, CategoryType)    

VALUES(1,'English','fiction');
```

and here is the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INSERT"
LINE 4: INSERT INTO Category (CategoryID,Name,CategoryType)
          ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "INSERT"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 45
```

Comment: The statement is valid. Which tool are you using to run that? Do you maybe have another statement in the editor before that which you did not properly terminate with a `;`?

Comment: The error is on lines 1, 2, or 3 of the code.

Comment: You need to end **every** statement with `;` - including the `set` statement

Answer (score 7):

You need a semi-colon at the end of the SET statement:

```
SET SEARCH_PATH TO work;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to just do an insert into that is schema qualified:

```
INSERT INTO work.Category (CategoryID, Name, CategoryType)    

VALUES(1,'English','fiction');
```

Or

```
SET SEARCH_PATH TO work;

/* Task 1 */

INSERT INTO Category (CategoryID, Name, CategoryType)    

VALUES(1,'English','fiction');
```

Either should fix the error.